# How to convert list array to Hexstring in c#?

Tags: c#, list, hex

I have a list array named "list". I need to convert this list into a hex string. I tried the code below but it hasn't worked.

```
    var  list = objIPLayer.Udp.Payload.ToList();
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(list);
```

I got this error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   `'System.BitConverter.ToString(byte[])'` has some invalid arguments**
>   when executed the following code.
>
> ```
> string hex = BitConverter.ToString(list);
> ```

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Its type is byte. **List<byte>**.

Comment: I got this error **The best overloaded method match for 'System.BitConverter.ToString(byte[])' has some invalid arguments** when executed the following code.                                     **string hex = BitConverter.ToString(list);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BitConverter.ToString(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) Expects `byte []` not `IEnumerable<byte>` or `List<byte>`.

Try following

```
var  list = objIPLayer.Udp.Payload.ToArray();
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(list);
```

Comment: Yup its working. I Needed to replace "-" in that string. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to an array first:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(list.ToArray());
```